# :not(:firstchild) is still selecting first child

Tags: css, dom, selector

I want to hide all divs except the first one
(Because its a form and i want to reveal the next div after clicking the first answer)

Just the thing is that its hiding everything.

DOM Structure

[image: DOM]

CSS

```
#precheck-form form div:not(:first-child){
    display: none;
  }
```

I tried aswell just hiding everything and with extra css

```
div:firstchild{
display:block;
}
```

but result was it was still hidden

In chrome inspector when i check first div inside the form it says

[image: inspector]

Comment: first-of-type instead

Comment: Well `:first-child` targets the `h3` as it is the first child, not the div. Therefore, the styles do not apply (or do, actually) because there is no `div` that is also a `:first-child`